# How to correctly use MatTableExporterModule to export data to excel?

Tags: html, angular, npm, angular-material, interpolation

I am using `mat-table-exporter` npm module within `Angular 9` to export mat table components.

I am able to export it correctly with `test` as the name of the exported file.

Previous working code:

```
<mat-table matTableExporter [dataSource]="dataSource" #exporter="matTableExporter">

<button mat-raised-button (click)="exporter.exportTable('csv', {fileName:'test',
   Props: {Author: 'myName'}})">
   Export
</button>
```

I also want to add timestamp in the name of the exported file for which I have written the following code:

New component Code:

```
exportTable(): void {
  this.exporter.exportTable('csv', {
    filename: `test-${new Date().toISOString()}`,
    Props: { 
      Author: 'myName'
    }
  })
}
```

New HTML Code:

```
<mat-table matTableExporter [dataSource]="dataSource" #exporter="matTableExporter">

<button mat-raised-button (click)="exportTable()">Export</button>
```

The above code is throwing an error:

```
TS2552: Cannot find name 'exporter'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want `exporter` available inside your component, you need to use `ViewChild`, your html code would stay the same, but the component should change to:

```
@ViewChild(MatTableExporterDirective, { static: true }) exporter: MatTableExporterDirective;
exportIt() {
  this.exporter.exportTable(ExportType.CSV, {
    fileName: "test",
    Props: {
      Author: "myName"
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was not defining its type hence was getting error.

Answer (score 2):

in Angular 15 worked- Export to excel
In
TS file -

```
 import { ExportType, MatTableExporterDirective, MatTableExporterModule } from 'mat-table-exporter';

  @ViewChild("exporter") exporter! : MatTableExporterDirective;
  download() {
    console.log("Downloading");
  this.exporter.exportTable(ExportType.XLSX, {
    fileName: "all-results",
    Props: {
      Author: "college-app-user"
    }
  });
  
}
```

In HTML template -

```
<mat-table matTableExporter [dataSource]="dataSource" #**exporter**="matTableExporter">
 <button mat-fab color="warn" aria-label="Example icon button with a home icon" (click)="download()">
```

**import** it in app.module file

```
 import { MatTableExporterModule } from 'mat-table-exporter';


  imports: [
  ........................
   MatTableExporterModule
  ],
```